# Sewer pipe cleanout

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent, sewer, cleanout

My house was built on a slab in1964 and has a walk out basement. There is a floor drain in my basement, along with a toilet & utility sink. Water from the main floor fixtures is backing up through the basement floor drain.  I am unable to find a cleanout inside or outside. However, there is a large stack with a plug about 3' from the floor in the basement. Is this the main line cleanout? Thanks for any assistance! 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTC1N.jpg)

Comment: A photo of the stack would be helpful is this stack a pipe possibly a back flow preventer.

Comment: I've added a photo.

Comment: I would think that could be a clean out. I have not seen copper used with cast but a snake would be easy to run down the access.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it’s probably a “wall cleanout”. We like them installed on a wall above (at a higher elevation) than a tub drain, or toilet, etc. so that the cap can be removed and the drain cleaned out (snake extended down the drain) without sewage gushing out the cleanout.

Comment: I agree but be cautious if the plug is bad you may have several feet of pipe full of waste water when you open it.

Comment: @EdBeal Hmmm...Copper to cast iron...very strange...I don’t understand that.

Comment: That's why I mentioned it also a brass plug those are very expensive items shown in the photo but I have only seen cast used in waste lines for residential.

Comment: Thanks for all the input!  I'll let you know what happens if I can get the plug out.